# SpriteKit SKView showsFields memory usage

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am curious about when `showsFields` is turned on, the memory usage increase extremely fast? It can growth up to 500MB under 30 seconds. If my mac only have 8GB of RAM, I probably have less than 8 minutes to debug before memory warning, it will be worst when debug on real device.

The screenshot below is tested from a real device (iOS 9.2).

[image: Memory Usage]

You can quickly try it by creating a SpriteKit project and turn `showsFields` on in `viewDidLoad()` method inside the view controller.

`skView.showsFields = true`

If you want to see what `showsFields` does, place this snippet inside the scene's `-didMoveToView(view:)` method.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let myField = SKFieldNode.springField()
    myField.position = CGPointMake(frame.midX, frame.midY)
    myField.strength = 1.0
    self.addChild(myField)
}
```

Here is `showsFields` discussion from Apple

> Discussion
>
> When this debugging option is enabled, each time a frame is rendered, an image is drawn behind your scene that shows the effects of any physics fields contained in the scene.

Comment: Have you tried on a real device? SpriteKit on the simulator is quite buggy and inefficient.

Comment: yup, memory warning force the app to quit

Comment: It's a bug. Expect it to be fixed in 2017. or 2018. But not tomorrow.

Comment: I just ran into this too. Eating memory FAST. Crashes app within a few seconds. iPhone 6 Plus, iOS 9.2.1, going up to hundreds of MBs in an instant. And I don't actually see any debug output!

Comment: the debug output is visual output, try add a physics field into your scene, it should be visible, still it can only last for short period of time before it finish up your memory.

Comment: I did add that. Im using the velocity field, which kind of works, but I have trouble debugging its SKRegion. WHich is why I tried showsFields, which did nothing but eat memory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the debug image drawn per frame is not being cleared up properly which, is probably leading to this memory leak.

Best will to file a bug report with Apple via https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/
so they know multiple people are having this issue and can hopefully give a higher priority.

Hope that helps.

Kind regards,
Mukund