# Velocity field in SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit

Anyone got Velocity Field in SpriteKit working?

Granted, I'm not sure I understand how it's supposed to work, but I'm wiring it up inside the Xcode UI, not code. My intention is to have dynamic spritenodes be pulled to a direction if they enter the area of that velocity field. Seeing as the velocity field node does not have a size of its own, I just assume I have to add it as a child of another spritenode (calling that *areaofvelocityfield*) which is not physical, but has a size, so that other dynamic spritenodes can enter into it and get affected by the force. So selecting the Velocity Field node, I select *areaofvelocityfield*.

Now, whatever I do, any dynamic node is affected by that force, whether or not they are inside areaofvelocityfield or in any vicinity of it. Whatever distance they are from the node containing the velocity field, and the velocity field itself, they are always affected and pulled in the vector of the field.

iOS 9.2.1. Xcode 7.2.

Comment: Did you try changing some of the other properties of the velocity field node, such as `falloff` and `strength`? Also, you can see a visual representation of any field node by setting `view.showsFields = true`.

Comment: I'm only using Xcode so far. I'll have to find a way to showsFields there. Or try to get the stuff running on device, but I hoped I wouldn't have to go there yet. Yes I tried falloff and other stuff like Min radius do nothing so far.

Comment: There is something called region. It seems it must be set, but it cannot be done in the UI. I think the field effect is "global" unless a region is set. Doh. There goes the UI again.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that .region must be set to the SKFieldNode. This cannot be done from Xcode. At least it cannot be done like this, which is my current code which works well:

```
SKSpriteNode* belt = (SKSpriteNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"belt"];

SKFieldNode* myfield = (SKFieldNode*)[self childNodeWithName:@"myfield"];
myfield.region = [[SKRegion alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(belt.size.width * 0.5, 10)];
```

Note that I am trying to make something like a "conveyor belt". The belt sprite is just a rectangle. The myfield is positioned at the same position as the belt. All nodes are placed directly onto the world, rootnode, no parenting is needed. Placing a field inside another node doesn't really have any effect as to the region it affects (or it might have, not sure here). For some reason I had to set the force field's width to half of the visible belt, or it would keep affecting whatever dynamic node that fell down onto the belt for too long.
Other values I used for the field are: strength 1, falloff 10, min. radius 1. Not sure what really made a difference, as this cannot be easily tested in the Xcode interface. A lot of trial and error is needed to figure out how this all works.

Regarding the size of a region: as the docs states, the size protrudes from the origin in all directions which means the width and height will actually be twice what you set.

Comment: btw .showsFields seems to do nothing, except eat up all memory on device. I had to remove that or the app crashes within a few seconds from memory overload. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903539/spritekit-skview-showsfields-memory-usage

Comment: If it's any consolation, many problems with fields in Scene Kit, too.